# Showing buttons if list view is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a list view which retrieves the data from sql data source. I am trying to make two buttons(Yes and No) and a label  outside the list view visible only if the list view is not empty. The process is: a person enter the information into text boxes and click the button retrieve, if the entered data exists in the database, the list view shows certain information.
I have the following code:

```
protected void btnExistingRetrive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     if (lstExisting.Items.Count>0 )
    {
       lblIsITYou.Visible = true;
       btnYes.Visible = true;
       btnNo.Visible = true;
    }

}
```

By default buttons and the label are not visible.
The problem is when i click on retrieve button it shows me the list view with the information but buttons a the label are still not visible. They became visible only when i double click the retrieve button. Please tell me what is my mistake?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you bind listview before checking the items count?

Comment: That is what i forgot. I just added it and it works correctly. Thanx a lot for a tip

Comment: please mark this as answer if this helped u so that other people knows this is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [ListView EmptyDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.emptydatatemplate.aspx)

```
  <asp:ListView ID="ContactsListView" 
    DataSourceID="ContactsDataSource" 
    runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
      <table runat="server" id="tblProducts">
        <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
      </table>
     </LayoutTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
        <tr runat="server">
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>' />
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("LastName") %>' />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EmptyDataTemplate>
          <table class="emptyTable" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <asp:Image ID="NoDataImage"
                  ImageUrl="~/Images/NoDataImage.jpg" 
                  runat="server"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                No records available.
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </EmptyDataTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this on postback instead of in the event.
In your Page_Load do something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool visible = (lstExisting.Items.Count > 0); // assuming it's never null
    lblIsITYou.Visible = visible;
    btnYes.Visible = visible;
    btnNo.Visible = visible;
}
```

If the above creates complications then do as I said first with postback:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        bool visible = (lstExisting.Items.Count > 0); // assuming it's never null
        lblIsITYou.Visible = visible;
        btnYes.Visible = visible;
        btnNo.Visible = visible;
    }
}
```